# How do I extract a texture .png from an FBX?

Tags: texturing

I've got a Black Ops 2 gun in FBX format. I want to extract the texture from it as a PNG or some type of image.
I am using the latest Blender [image]

Comment: how did you open the fbx file format and when did blender support it?

Answer (score 3):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!
Go to UV Editor in Blender, and click on the image icon at the top to select the texture to view. Then click the Image button panel thing and you can save it from there.